# malted balls centers

Tags: candy

How can make malted milk ball centers - not the chocolate covering? If I mix malted milk powder with any liquid it just melts into it. I don't have any way to compress the powder mechanically, which might work. There used to be pressed hard malted candies but I can't find them anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The ingredients of Whoppers are:

> SUGAR; CORN SYRUP; PARTIALLY HYDROGENATED PALM KERNEL OIL; WHEY (MILK); MALTED MILK (BARLEY MALT; WHEAT FLOUR; MILK; SALT; SODIUM BICARBONATE); COCOA; CONTAINS 2% OR LESS OF: RESINOUS GLAZE; SORBITAN TRISTEARATE; SOY LECITHIN; SALT; NATURAL AND ARTIFICIAL FLAVOR; CALCIUM CARBONATE; TAPIOCA DEXTRIN

I'm guessing that the sugar, corn syrup, palm kernel oil, cocoa, glaze, and lecithin are in the chocolate coating. This leaves you with a few things to play with for the filling. The wheat flour could be adding some bulk and helping to hold the filling together. However!

Tapioca dextrin... the plot thickens! Tapioca dextrin is a filler made from cassava that has almost no flavor. It is used as a bulking agent in things like sauces and dressings, but it is also used as a binding agent. One of it's main functions is to hold [medication together](http://inrfood.com/ingredients/4090) in pills, so that could easily also be holding malted milk powder together in the filling.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the "holding together" part. Generally, starches thicken but do not hold together, it is proteins which really bind. Also it is listed at the end, even after the flavor, so there really isn't enough of it to do anything, I could imagine it being dusted on the surface the things are put to cool or similar. The whey can bind, depending on how it is used, and the palm oil can be emulsified with the malted milk for a nice smooth paste.

Comment: @rumtscho I added a link explaining the binding. Wikipedia also has [a page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextrin#Uses) on dextrins showing several uses as binders. Starches in food are not frequently used to hold things together, but outside of the food industry it's pretty common (wheatpaste, etc). I also don't think the palm oil is binding the center because as you said, it would be a paste. The oil wouldn't dry to leave the centers crisp.

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go: http://creativeepicure.blogspot.com/2012/02/homemade-malted-milk-balls.html

- 4 egg whites
- 1/8 teaspoon Cream of Tarter
- 1/2 Cup White Sugar
- 1 Cup Confectioners Sugar
- 4 Tbsp Cocoa Powder
- 5 Tbsp Malt Powder
- 2 Tbsp Turbinado Sugar

Have fun!

Comment: eek, a recipe!!!

Comment: I don't think the traditional (Whoppers type) malted milk ball center is meringue based.  It is much harder and crunchier than that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a meringue. You heat the sugar, corn syrup, milk and malted barley(malted milk powder) together to 300 degrees. Hard candy stage. Remove from heat and add sodium bicarbonate (baking soda). It will rise 2-3 times in volume. Do not over stir. Poor onto a sill pad. And let cool for 10-20 min.  It will have a light airy and crunchy texture. Break into pieces and coat with chocolate.